# Duplicate records in chart ssrs

Tags: report, ssrs-2008

I have 2 datasets as below:

select Name, CIType, count(*) as NumDuplicates
from CI
group by Name, CIType
having count(*) > 1;

select Name, CIType, count(*) as NumNonDuplicates
from CI
group by Name, CIType
having count(*) = 1;

The first one identifies duplicate entries while the second one identifies unique entries.

What I would like to do is to combine the results of both datasets in one chart as below:

[image]

The chart would show the duplicate and non duplicate entries for each CI type.

Whatever I have tried so far is not working...

Any help/guidance would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily use two datasets in a single chart like that. It would be much easier if you did this in your dataset query.

You could use a single query

```
SELECT [Name], CIType, count() as RowCount 
    , IIF(Count(*) >1 , 1, 0) AS HasDuplicates
FROM CI 
GROUP BY [Name], CIType
```

This will give you the counts and a column that indicates whether there are duplicates or not.

You could swap you the `1, 0` for something more meaningful that you could use in the chart legend e.g.`, IIF(Count(*) >1 , "Has Duplicates", "None Duplicate") AS HasDuplicates`

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance. That was very helpful.

Comment: No problem, if this does eventually answer your question, please mark the answer as accepted (Check mark under the vote up//down buttons). This helps others find answered to similar questions.